# Displaying a Wordpress post list

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd appreciate any help on this! I am trying to display a list of posts in a widget, sorted by a custom field metadata value.

I tweaked code I found here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/

My code:

```
<?php 

// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'date_time_code',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));

if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
        setup_postdata( $post )
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The resulting output shows the correct number of links (corresponding to the actual number of events posts) but the link text and links are incorrect. Links are to whichever page the list is currently being displayed on and link text is the current page title. So on the home page, the list reads 
Home
Home
Home
and the links are all to to the home page.

How do I get the links to display and link correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you include the file containing the code. If you use `get_template_part` WP properly sets up all necessary global vars for you, if you use a normal `include` for example you will need to add this to the top of your file:

`global $post;`

WP loves those global variables and it's a real hassle to work with. You can basically bring down an entire site by using the wrong variable name.